# The use of `do..return` expressions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, return-value

For this fonction:

```
envoyerMessage' :: SmartMail -> CompteSmail -> Trame -> (SmartMail, CompteSmail)
```

For the sake of testing, I try to simply return the element passed without any changes.

My problem is this:

```
envoyerMessage' ssm csm tr = (ssm, csm)
```

works as intended, but with `do..return`:

```
envoyerMessage' ssm csm tr = do
                             return (ssm, csm)
```

I get this error message:
[error about being unable to match actual and expected type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuJZj.png)

Why does `return` doesn't return the expected type?

edit: I often see `return` being associated with `IO type` in the function description, is it related to this issue? Will the value obtained from a `return` always be of `IO type`?

Comment: `return` is not a special keyword. It is a function. It has type `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`. I don't think applying this function is what you are looking to do (for one, as its type signature indicates, its the type of its result is not the same as its input type). It is a shame that `return` has the name that it has because it is really unrelated to what `return` means in many other languages.

Comment: BTW nowadays `pure` is preferred to `return` (according to hlint), probably because `return` is confusing in exactly this way.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast reply, I did understand that it was a function, but I didn't thought that the use of `Monad` would alter it's type. I guess my problem here is the understanding of `Monad`.

Comment: You *can* use `do` notation to write pure code; you just need to omit `return`/`pure` and avoid binding statements (`pattern <- expression`), e.g. `do (ssm, csm)` is equivalent to `(ssm, csm)`. `let` statements will also work: `do { let { x = 1; y = 2 }; let { z = 3 }; (x, y, z) }` is equivalent to `let { x = 1; y = 2 } in let { z = 3 } in (x, y, z)`. The only potential advantage of using `do` notation everywhere is that you wouldn’t need to change the syntax of a pure function if you added effects later—but that’s fairly rare and not idiomatic, so it’s not really worth it imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` is a function of type `Monad m => a -> m a`, so when you pass in a value of type `(SmartMail, CompteSmail)`, you get back a value of type `m (SmartMail, CompteSmail)` for some monad `m` (for example `IO (SmartMail, CompteSmail)` or `Maybe (SmartMail, CompteSmail)`). Since that's not what you want here, you shouldn't use `return`.

`do` notation is unrelated to this. `do` is simply a syntactic shortcut around the `>>` and `>>=` operators. When you use `do` with a single expression, it does nothing at all. In other words `envoyerMessage' ssm csm tr = do return (ssm, csm)` is exactly the same as just `envoyerMessage' ssm csm tr = return (ssm, csm)`.